# Files corrupting without changing the date modified

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption, date-modified

We have files on our network that are being corrupted.

ex. of corrupted file:
name = foobar.indd
date modified = 2/6/2014

so the file was last modified on the 2/6/2014 then was opened just fine on the 2/10/2014 and not modified. On 2/17/2014 a user tried to open the file and it is corrupt.

the date modified is still 2/6/2014. What could modify/corrupt the file without changing the date modified value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your hard disk is going bad.

You should check out the logs on the server to see if there are any more clues.

I'm not sure about Windows file-servers reporting back errors to the client machines. I had a similar thing happen on a GNU/Linux samba server once. It was hard to see the problem at first, because all the files appeared to be there, and even copying the files seemed to work. But when I logged into the server, I could see a lot of error messages.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. We checked the server log and there was two ntfs errors. We ran chkdsk to clean up the errors because thats what the error said to do. The files still remain corrupt. In order to rule out the possibility of an application doing this. is it possible for a program to edit/corrupt a file without changing the date modified

Comment: There is always the potential, if you have a malicious app, it can get the modification time, modify the file, and then set the modification time back. But otherwise the filesystem will set the timestamp automatically to whenever it was modified/created. So unless you are suspecting some malware, I would recommend some intensive disk scanning/repairing. I would do a backup beforehand to at least copy all the intact data, then swap out the disk for a new one as soon as possible. The backup procedure will also likely let you know of any other problem sectors you weren't aware of yet.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment. I'm going to mark this answer as accepted. If it turns out to be malware or something else I will update the question/answer